# SQLLite: How to renumber a auto-increment field?

Tags: sqlite

I have two different CSV files which I have merged and imported into a single table in a SQLite3 database. Each CSV file contained a column called ID. Since, some of the ID's are duplicates (across the CSV files) and this is a primary key field, I need a way to completely  renumber the ID field for each row in the table.

The ID field is also an auto-increment field.

So, what I would like to do is to run a SQL command or some other method where the ID for each row of the table would be reset to ensure uniqueness. For example, the ID field for the first row will be set to 1 the next to 2 and so on.

Note, it is not so important that it begin with 1. Ensuring primary key uniqueness is the goal here. It doesn't matter what number it starts at. There are also no foreign key relations so that is not an issue.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, in my case, I figured out that it was easiest to not import the ID column. Rather, I imported everything else and then added an ID field of type auto-increment. Once I did that, everything was re-numbered as I wanted.